# Capture Flash / Flex redraw DisplayObject event?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, event-handling, displayobject

I'm trying to capture the redraw event for some MovieClip / Sprite objects that are in a Scroll area.

Ideally, should be able to capture the event when Flash Player itself redraws the objects as can be seen with "Show Redraw Regions" in FP Debug.

I've tried to use the Event.RENDER to capture this, but it even fires when the object is not visible / redrawn.

Is there any native flash event that can help me capture this accurately?

TIA!

Comment: Seem the redraw region cannot detected by script. Event.RENDER will call if the object is in the display list even it is not visible.

Comment: thanks. any way to figure out if an object is visible in the viewport without looping through and checking coordinates?

Comment: what problem to you need the redraw event for? theres probably a better way of solving it.

Comment: you could probably do this with getBounds or one of the other similar methods - have a look at this: http://actionsnippet.com/?p=1413

Comment: Brilliant. object.transform.pixelBounds gets me the info I needed to decide whether to redraw or not.

Comment: In my case, I have a "Glass" surface that's fixed.  It needs to be redrawn when the image underneath it changes, which could change for any reason (user interaction, something animating under it, etc.)  Without a redraw event, its impossible to efficiently redraw the surface's glass distortion effect.  A blendShader WOULD be perfect, handling the updates automatically, BUT there's this stupid catch that it can't sample anything other than the output coordinate, which makes distortions impossible.  See last note: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSB19E965E-CCD2-4174-8077-8E5D0141A4A8.html

Answer (score 0):

So far, looks like there is no way to capture the Flash Player's redraw event.

However, to solve this specific problem I used 
- On the display object that I manually redraw, check the bounds with object.transform.pixelBounds

- Use Event.RENDER to fire the event so each objects redraws as needed if they are within the display area as per bounds.

Not perfect, but does the job. Wish FP had this feature for people who do detail level work.